# How to create a time of 9pm today in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get a `smalldatetime` value of "9pm today" in a query. I thought I could use

```
DATEADD(HOUR, 21, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

but SQL Server doesn't like that - I get the error

> The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data
>   type date.

Suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty simple, just cast `date` back to `datetime` after casting to `date`.

Thus you'll get `current_date 00:00:00` and then add 21 hours:

```
select dateadd(hh, 21, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

Comment: yeah I thought of this 1 minute after I typed in the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

it is because dateadd's 3rd parameter should be datetime type, not date.

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 21, CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date, GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 0):

just add 21 / 24.0 to todays date

```
 Select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1, getDate()), 1) + (21 / 24.0)
```

First part, `dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1, getDate()), 1)`, strips time from getdate(),

second part, `+ (21 / 24.0)`, adds fractional part of day equal to 9 am

This works because internally, SQL Server represents datetimes as two integers, one for the date, (number of days since 1 Jan 1900), and a second integer for the time, (number of `ticks` since midnight), which it combines into a decimal value where the integer part is the date integer, and the decimal part is the fraction of one day, so if you add 0.5 to a date, you get noon on that day, etc.

or, for comparison, using `dateadd` for hours,

```
 Select dateadd(hour, 21, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1, getDate()), 1))
```

Comment: Yes, `cast` won't work here to strip time, you need to do it with `dateadd`, `datediff`.

Comment: You would have to change this to 21/24.0. However this is really confusing code and I am not a big fan of using addition to datetime datatypes. It is much clearer using dateadd.

Comment: ahhh, I didn't see the pm, I edited answer to make it 9 PM.  and Yes, this is in fact equivalent to using `dateadd()`, and, I agree, not as clear if you don't understand the internals. I only use it because to replace the simple addition with `dateadd()`, the second argument of the `dateAdd()` has to be whatever complex expression you need to get the date you are adding the hours to... and often, that expression is complex enough that embedded inside the `dateAdd()`, it is less clear than the simple addition.